Ошибка при вызове запроса на сервер
Ошибка возникает при запросе на сервер.
После запроса на сервер все крашится и вызывает такую ошибку

WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value

    async getOne(req, res){
        const {id} = req.body
        const brandsName = await Brand.findOne({where: {id}})
        return res.json(brandsName.name)
    }

Вот сам запрос
export const fetchGetModelAuto = async (id) => {
    const {data} = await $host.get('api/brand/name', id)
    return data
}

А это куда мне надо присвоить
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetchGetModelAuto(id).then(data =>  setModelAuto(data))

    }, [])


const {id} = req.body -> выведете в консоль console.log(id, req.body) и посмотрите, что там у вас лежит

@SwaD undefined и пустой объект

Ну как бы вот... Сначала убедитесь, что данные отправляются с клиента, потом разбирайтесь, почему req.data пусто. Да и если вы отправляете get запрос, у него body быть не может. Нужен post запрос. Либо передавать параметр в самом url get запроса

У запросов get нет body... Но есть query.

комментарий ksa по делу. покажите описание роутера в экспресс

@nörbörnën
router.get('/name', BrandControllers.getOne) // это тут
router.get('/', BrandControllers.getAll)```

а какой Request URL в браузере? это можно посмотреть в консоли
